# wordpress pretty links - only homepage works

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

When I turn on "pretty" links in wordpress,
only homepage shows, other pages are suddenly "404 not found",
.htaccess file seems to be fine

Comment: This is most likely a server configuration settings.  Some hosting providers ignore `.htaccess` files, and the Apache module `mod_rewrite` must be installed on the server as well for pretty permalinks.  Submit a support ticket asking about this to your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the file itself may be fine, but does your provider allows you to use .htaccess file by default? My does not.

Go to your hosting administration and look for:
**HTACCESS** or **Mod_rewrite** settings and allow those.